# How to update database using dataset, tablemanager, and bindingsource?

Tags: winforms, dataset

This is a pretty small program, so I just used the autogenerated code for my datasource and dragged/dropped a datagridview on my WinForm. I'm trying to manually update a column in a row, but it fails each time I get to the "UpdateAll" of my tablemanager. Here's my code for double click of cell content:

```
    private void dgv1DataGridView_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string delMemberID = dgv1DataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            ds1DataSet.Table1.Rows[ds1DataSet.Table1.Rows.IndexOf(ds1DataSet.Table1.FindByMemberID(delMemberID))][9] = MemberID.ToString();
            this.Validate();
            this.bs1BindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.ds1DataSet);
            MessageBox.Show("Replacement Successful");
            this.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Replacement Failed");
        }
    }
```

My expectations are; when a user double clicks anywhere inside a row of the datagridview, it will update that row with a different "MemberID" for that column, save the data everywhere (including database), and then close the form (to return the parent form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, my tableAdapterManager wasn't linked to my TableAdapter on that form - once I linked them, the above code worked fine.

To be more precise, I clicked on the design view of my form and clicked the the tableAdapterManager at the bottom of the design window. Then looking in the "Properties" window, I noticed that the TableAdapter was blank (if you used a wizard to create the DataSource, then it will be named the same as the table in your DataSource). Once I selected the correct name for the TableAdapter, everything worked perfect.